# Binding Generic Objects in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Having following POJO class

```
public class Person{
   public String mapId;
   public Object parameters;
   ..GETTERS..SETTERS..
}
```

Using above POJO, A view is created in controller and for **PARAMETERS** field a class is mapped to it.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/view")
public String view(@RequestParam(value="id",required=true)String id,Model model){

        Person person = new Person();
        person.setParameters(new Aged());

        model.addAttribute("person", person);
        return "person.jsp";
}
```

When form sumbit from *Client side*, **PARAMETERS** field mapped class gets removed.

```
<form:form commandName="person" action="${saveUrl }" method="post" cssClass="form-horizontal">
    <form:input path="parameters.limit" cssClass="span12"/>
</form:form>
```

Help??

Comment: This is not a solution, but the name of "Map" is not the luckiest choice for you pojo.

Comment: Tht's not the answer what I excepted. Name "Map" is just a sample name.

Comment: I assume Spring cannot map your submitted data by type, because it's too generic.